# C# asp.net application, changes to Site.css do not seem to affect Site.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I just started an asp.net c# project and I was trying to change the text-align of the .title and background color of the .header. I add the required code to the style sheet, but nothing changes in the header of the form. I'm probably missing something simple here, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please add your code... your style sheet reference and your header. And also make sure it is just caching.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, your CSS file is cached, so you will need to clear your cache to see any changes in most browsers.

Comment: @AaronS how do you clear the cache before each run of the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stylesheets are usually cached by the browser to speed up browsing.

You can either force-refresh (SHIFT+F5) or append a value to the stylesheet path to cache-bust it.

```
style.css?v1
```

By changing `v1` whenever you want a change to be forced out to all browsers, it will replace the cached version as resources are cached per URI.

Comment: thanks, simply hitting F5 refreshed the page. I usually used dreamweaver to create web sites, I think it must do this automatically when you view a page.

Answer (score 0):

Just try stopping your Local development server and do clean and build solution before running the application.
Even clear your temporary internet folder which may contain stale copy of your css file.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking in the markup view , you should see an options that says view in browser. This should reload anything cached.